got error keyset does not exists when working with ec keys
I have a EC key pair that I want to store in the window keys store so that my services can used it. First I exported them into a pfx file:
public void ExportECKeyPairToPfx(string pfxPath, string password)
    {
        // Generate EC key pair
        var curve = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1"); // P-256 curve
        var domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H, curve.GetSeed());
        
        var keyPairGenerator = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
        var keyGenParams = new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 256);
        keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenParams);
        var keyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

        // Create self-signed certificate
        var certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
        var serialNumber = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new SecureRandom());
        var issuerDN = new X509Name("CN=Self Signed Certificate");
        var subjectDN = new X509Name("CN=Self Signed Certificate");
        
        certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);
        certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
        certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.UtcNow.Date);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddYears(1));
        certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(keyPair.Public);
        
        // Sign the certificate with the private key
        var signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA256WITHECDSA", keyPair.Private);
        var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);

        // Create PFX (PKCS#12) store and add the certificate with private key
        var store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
        var certificateEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(certificate);
        
        store.SetKeyEntry("EC Key", new AsymmetricKeyEntry(keyPair.Private), new[] { certificateEntry });

        // Save to file
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(pfxPath))
        {
            store.Save(fileStream, password.ToCharArray(), new SecureRandom());
        }
    }

Next I stored it to the windows key store:
public void ImportPfxToLocalMachine(string pfxPath, string password, StoreName storeName = StoreName.My)
    {
        try
        {
            // Read the certificate file
            var pfxBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pfxPath);
            
            // Create X509Certificate2 object from PFX file
            // Note: We use X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet 
            // to ensure the private key is stored in the machine store
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
                pfxBytes,
                password,
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | 
                X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | 
                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            // Open the LocalMachine store
            using (var store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                // Open store with ReadWrite rights
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

                // Add certificate to store
                store.Add(certificate);

                Console.WriteLine($"Certificate with thumbprint {certificate.Thumbprint} successfully imported to LocalMachine\\{storeName}");
                
                store.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error importing certificate: {ex.Message}");
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}");
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

Until this step it works properly but when I tried to read the private key it throws keyset does not exists:
public void GetCertificateByThumbprint(string thumbprint, StoreName storeName = StoreName.My)
    {
        using (var store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            // Find certificate by thumbprint
            var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                thumbprint,
                false); // false = don't validate certificate

            store.Close();

            if (certificates.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception($"Certificate with thumbprint {thumbprint} not found.");

            var certificate = certificates[0];
            certificate.GetECDsaPrivateKey();   //ERROR HERE
        }
    }

But weirdly, when i tried with RSA key pair there is no problem. Any pointers?
